# iPhone: cannot see any labels on my core plot graph

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I'm building a graph with core plot, that works fine except that I do not see any labels on the x and y axis. I can only see major and minor ticks but no value next to them. There must be something I'm missing but I do not know what. Also, is it possible to add a label for each axis, for instance: x (hours), y (value).

The graph I am working on is part of the first row of a listview.

The code is:

```
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GraphCustomViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

            for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            {
                if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[GraphCustomViewCell class]])
                {
                    cell = (GraphCustomViewCell *)currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }

            CGRect frame = cell.contentView.bounds;

            CPLayerHostingView *hostingView = [[CPLayerHostingView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
            [cell addSubview:hostingView];

            // Create graph
            CPTheme *theme = [CPTheme themeNamed:kCPPlainWhiteTheme];
            graph = (CPXYGraph *)[theme newGraph];  

            // Add graph to view
            hostingView.hostedLayer = graph;
            graph.paddingLeft = 50.0;
            graph.paddingTop = 5.0;
            graph.paddingRight = 5.0;
            graph.paddingBottom = 25.0;

            // Adjust graph
            float xmax = [[[self arrayFromData] objectForKey:@"data"] count];
            CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
            plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                           length:CPDecimalFromFloat(xmax)];
            plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                           length:CPDecimalFromFloat(3000)];

            CPTextStyle *blackText = [[CPTextStyle textStyle] color:[CPColor blackColor]];
            CPLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
            lineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor blackColor];
            lineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

            axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5"] decimalValue];
            axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
            axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
            axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
            axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
            axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 4.0f;
            axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 8.0f;
            axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset = 3.0f;
            axisSet.xAxis.labelTextStyle = blackText;


            axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"500"] decimalValue];
            axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
            axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
            axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
            axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
            axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 4.0f;
            axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 8.0f;
            axisSet.yAxis.labelOffset = 1.0f;

            CPScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[[CPScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
            dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"MyGraph";
            dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.f;
            dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor greenColor];
            dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
            [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];

            // Put an area gradient under the plot above
            CPColor *areaColor = [CPColor colorWithComponentRed:0.3 
                                                          green:1.0
                                                           blue:0.3
                                                          alpha:0.3];
            CPGradient *areaGradient = [CPGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:areaColor 
                                                                  endingColor:[CPColor clearColor]];
            areaGradient.angle = -90.0f;
            CPFill *areaGradientFill = [CPFill fillWithGradient:areaGradient];
            dataSourceLinePlot.areaFill = areaGradientFill;
            dataSourceLinePlot.areaBaseValue = CPDecimalFromString(@"1.75");
```

Thanks a lot,
Regards,
Luc

ps: quick edit, I have checked with graph.name = "my graph", but nothing is displayed on the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was due to the fact there were too many labels to display and also because the axis did not went far enough in the negative area => no place to display the labels. But, graph.name does not display a name of the graph...